# Does Microsoft Graph support CAML queries for SharePoint Online lists?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, caml-query, microsoft-graph

Can you query lists in SharePoint Online via Microsoft Graph using CAML queries? Beta/Preview functionality would be ok for me to use.

If not: any alternative apporoaches to use similar sophisticated BeginsWith/Contains/Eq etc.-logic? Search would not suffice here.

Answer (score 0):

Graph API also has filtering support. Sample below:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{id}/root/children?filter=name eq '{name}'
```